# How can i fix not responding error in python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface

i want to make a GUI for a python script but wen i press start i get not responding in GUI

```
layout = [[sg.Output(size=(60,10))],
    [sg.Button('Exit'),sg.Button('Start')]]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
event, values = window.read()
while True:
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Start':                  
        for email in emails:                                                                                  
            if counter < 2:                
                if len(email.strip()) > 0:
                    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
                        server.login(sender_email, password)
                        try:
                            server.sendmail(
                                sender_email, email, message.as_string()
                            )
                            #print("Adresa " + email + " este corecta!")
                        except smtplib.SMTPDataError:
                                track +=1                               
                                print("Prea multe email-uri trimise")
                                print("Adresa de email " + sender_email + " a fost inlocuita cu " + sender_mails[track] + " !")
                                emails.append(email)
                                sender_email = sender_mails[track]
                        except smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused:
                            print("Adresa " + email + " nu este corecta!")
                            #counter += 1
                        except:
                            print ("Eroare necunoscuta")
            else:
                while time.time() - start_time <= 60:
                    pass
            if time.time() - start_time >= 60:
                start_time = time.time()
                counter = 0
                emails.append(email)
        break                                                                       
window.close()
```

This is the code.. After i press start the script freze andi cant close it. I use it PySimpleGUI. After pressing the start button, the GUI freezes until all the action in the start syntax is finished. I want to be able to use the interface while those actions are in progress.

Comment: what library do You use for GUI? also it probably is because of the while True loop, program can't break out of it

Comment: `if counter < 2:` must be false... so the code waits 60 seconds here: `while time.time() - start_time <= 60: pass`

Comment: @Matiiss i use PySimpleGUI

Answer (score 0):

So I haven't run your code, but I would guess that your while loop is what freezes your code:

```py
    else:
        while time.time() - start_time <= 60:
            pass
```

If you enter this loop, your program will stay there for 60 seconds.

Comment: He cant enter in that else because counter in not increment now.

Comment: #counter += 1 so counter remain 0

Comment: Where do you initialize `counter`? Not in the code shown above...

Answer (score 0):

Your GUI will not respond if you do something for long time. The best way is to use multi-threading and call `window.write_event_value(key, value)` to generate an event.

From here, you can find 11 scripts with filename startswith `Demo_Multithreaded_xxxx.py` to demo multi-threading

[Demo Programs](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/tree/master/DemoPrograms)